# Store objects in different containers, and access them with a uniform interface

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

I have a set of objects linked together, stored in multiple containers of different types.
I want to use an uniform interface, independent of the specific containers.

So far, I could find two ways to do this, and I would like to know if there are any better ways to achieve the same result.

As a first option, I am using a plain pointer to access the linked object, since iterators are class specific. The downside of this is that a container may be reallocated, making all pointers to it invalid.

As a second option, I use two indices, one for the container I want to use, an one for the position inside that container. An extra function `GetData()` returns the required value.

Is there a more (run time) efficient way to implement the same functionality?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <vector>


struct C {
    int data = 0;

    // Option 1
    const C *pOther = 0;    // Can I use an iterator?

    // Option 2
    size_t  idOther = 0;
    uint8_t idContainer = 0;

    C(int i) : data(i) {}
};

std::vector<C> vc;
std::deque<C>  dc;
std::list<C>   lc;

// Option 2
int GetData(size_t id, uint8_t idc) {
    switch(idc) {
        case 1:
            return vc[id].data;
        case 2:
            return dc[id].data;
        case 3:
            return std::next(lc.begin(), id)->data;
    }

    return -1;
}


int main()
{
    C c1(1), c2(2), c3(3);
    vc.push_back(c1);
    dc.push_back(c2);
    lc.push_back(c3);

    // Option 1
    vc[0].pOther = &dc[0];
    dc[0].pOther = &lc.front();
    lc.front().pOther = &vc[0];

    std::cout << "\nvc[0].data = " << vc[0].data << "  pOther->data = " << vc[0].pOther->data
              << "\ndc[0].data = " << dc[0].data << "  pOther->data = " << dc[0].pOther->data
              << "\nlc.front().data = " << lc.front().data << "  pOther->data = " << lc.front().pOther->data
              << std::endl;

    // Option 2
    vc[0].idOther = 0;
    vc[0].idContainer = 2;
    dc[0].idOther = 0;
    dc[0].idContainer = 3;
    lc.front().idOther = 0;
    lc.front().idContainer = 1;

    std::cout << "\nvc[0].data = " << vc[0].data << "  GetData = " << GetData(vc[0].idOther, vc[0].idContainer)
              << "\ndc[0].data = " << dc[0].data << "  GetData = " << GetData(dc[0].idOther, dc[0].idContainer)
              << "\nlc.front().data = " << lc.front().data << "  GetData = " << GetData(lc.front().idOther, lc.front().idContainer)
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can also use a type-erased iterators if you can pay for virtual calls. *...more efficient way...* - Please define "efficient".

Comment: @Evg - I mean run-time efficiency.

Comment: Have your `struct C` contain some unique identifier (or unique set of identifying data) that identifies each object.  Then just pass the identifier to your function, and your function searches the containers for an object with that identifier.   There are algorithms in the standard library to efficiently help with that.  This has a runtime impact if there are a lot of containers (or containers with lots of elements) but the caller needn't worry about keeping track of containers.  And, if you add/remove a container, only your function needs to change - not its callers.  Maintainability benefit.

Comment: Are pointers not run-time efficient for you?

Comment: What is a template ?